# How to restrict input in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, input, jtable, validation

I am using in my program an editable JTable. My question is:

How would you restrict the input that is written in the table?

Comment: please what is  `I appreaciate your answer!!! `, remove that, back to your question, have look at isEditable, you can to set that for Column, or Column & Row index

Comment: for input validations, formating, input mask, verifier to use proper XxxCellEditor

Comment: but that just makes the cell not/editable! My Problem is that the editable cells should only get selected Input, like Integers and no Chars ect. How would you integrate that?

Comment: thx mKobel for your answer! What do you mean by XxxCellEditor and the set for proper Colume.Class, pls provide some further explanation.

Comment: please I'm leaving this thread, [bunch of code, descriptions about by (excluding my person 2nd - 8place)](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jtable/topusers)

Comment: What do you mean by "*restrict*"? Do you want the user to only be able enter dates, numbers, text, elephants??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the tutorial "[How to Use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)" and review the section titled "Using Other Editors"